how to show user in TokenSerializer dj-rest-auth
I'm trying to return UserSerializer after successful login through dj-rest-auth.
I followed the steps that were told in
After login the `rest-auth`, how to return more information?
which has a similar issue, but it still doesn't show information about User after logging in.
what i'm getting after successful login
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'blink.user.serializers.TokenSerializer',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'blink.user.serializers.UserSerializer'
}
#settings.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude_fields = kwargs.pop('exclude_fields', None)
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context and 'view' in self.context and self.context['view'].__class__.__name__ == 'UsersView':
            exclude_fields = ['subscription', 'avatar', 'file']
        if exclude_fields:
            for field_name in exclude_fields:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'last_login', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        model = User

class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = '__all__'

#User.serializers.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from blink.common.models import Base
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        default='',
        unique=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')
 

#user/models.py



I tackled my own problem, the only issue was with my settings.py
dj-rest-auth changed the way you configure your token serializer from 3.0.0 version it works fine also for latest (6.0.0)
REST_AUTH = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'blink.user.serializers.TokenSerializer',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'blink.user.serializers.UserSerializer',

instead of , which worked only for dj-rest-auth <= 2.2.8 versions
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'TOKEN_SERIALIZER': 'blink.user.serializers.TokenSerializer',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'blink.user.serializers.UserSerializer'
}


class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email', read_only=True)
    full_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.get_full_name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ['key', 'created', 'user', 'email', 'full_name']

This is how you can show if you want to show some fields. Make sure your TokenModel has a relationship with User model

It still gives me nothing, but key. Maybe this issue appears, because I have the latest version of dj-rest-auth?
I'm currently using 6.0.0 version.

how do you get can you show me the models?

Sorry for late response @Tanveer, my notifications got somehow turned off. I updated my post added user.models.py for description. In my previous project DRF I have the same configuration as here and everything works. However, the configuration used in new project doesn't work. By "configuration" I mean serializers for users and settings.py.
